# How to transfer ownership of a Drive file with PHP API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have a master account, lets call it master@domain.com. I do a lot of Drive PHP API processes on this account (not using a service account for this as it's only for this account) like creating dynamic folder structures, creating documents, modifying permissions, etc. The thing is some users in the same domain.com will be uploading files and sharing them to this account, but for security and integrity purposes I need to be the owner of this files. As I can't trust that the employees will always remember to give me manual ownership I need to do this with the API.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to use a service account to impersonate the users so I can do an insertPermission(), or can i do an update permission from the master@domain.com account? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might help https://github.com/pinoyyid/googleDriveTransferOwnership

It sets up a folder, called say "Project 1". Any files placed in that folder will have their ownership changed to whoever the owner of "Project 1" is.

Comment: Oops forgot to mention that I'm using PHP :S

Comment: The github project I pasted, pretty much does what you're looking for. You can do two things with it. Firstly, you can install it somewhere and run it standalone from  cron. It isn't a library, it's an executable application. Secondly, feel free to read the code and extract the logic into whatever programming language you choose.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10496637)

Comment: @swidmann welcome to SO. Noobs are an important constituency in any community and your role within SO is no exception. I guess reaching 2,000 rep gives you some kind of buzz, so congrats on that. Thank you for taking the time to comment on a subject, about which you have no practical experience, or contribution to make. If you read the OP's question (before the later edit to add "in php", which is a red herring anyway), and then match it to the readme of the cited git repo, you will see that it's a pretty close match. ie. the code in the repo does what he's asking for.

Comment: Well I'm really sad, that I can't give you ten upvotes for this comment. I've never been offended in such an eloquent and "funny to read" way. My english is also not the best, so I can't answer you in a way you would deserve it. If you have a blog, post me the link, I'll read it every day. Indeed you are right, I have no clue about the google drive api, but in this case it isn't needed at all. Your answer just misses some explanation (whether wrong programming language or not), maybe you should take a second look on [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I bumped to a task like this, the code in Java was helpful and I managed to make it work in PHP. Thanks @pinoyyid